# Varios modals en una página y quiero que se activen con click

Tags: jquery, modal, click

Tengo varios modals en una página y quiero activarlos con .click. Logro que se activen con .hover, pero no con .click. Sí funciona si uso onclick, pero me marca error de sintaxis.

```javascript
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function() {
        var modalId = $(this).data('target');
        $(modalId).modal('show');

      });
    });
```

Comment: ¿Que vesión de bootstrap estas usando?  En bootstrap 5 el atributo es `data-bs-toggle` y no `data-toggle`

Answer (score 0):

Estoy usando Bootstrap 4.5.2 y, [como indica masterguru en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/523703/varios-modals-en-una-p%c3%a1gina-y-quiero-que-se-activen-con-click#comment927731_523703), usando el data-bs-toggle se solucionó el problema.

Comment: Si sos quien formuló la pregunta, [solicitá combinar tus perfiles de usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact).